# Unable to call local Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to using Visual Studio to run a web api. I have an MVC Web API which I am trying to call locally but keep getting a 404. I am sure the API works fine because a friend of mine has hosted it on another server and I can call it fine. However, I am not sure how to get it running locally. Will building the code automatically get it hosted?

I am trying to call:

```
https://localhost/MyAPI/Action
```

Action is one of the action methods in a controller that should return "hello" but I get a 404 when trying to call the API. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your information is not sufficient. It's not clear what your bindings are, how the method is declared, etc.

Comment: In VS if you right click the startup app (the web app) and choose properties the Web tab lists servers. Mine (for example) is IIS Express,http://localhost:51137/ - it should indicate how the site in dev mode is hosted and what port it's on.

Comment: @NeilThompson Ok, mine also says IIS Express,localhost:10103/

I tried calling the API with the port included. Same issue. 404

Comment: and from VS if you choose DEBUG > Start without debugging it will launch the app in a browser - from there you can try the url? Make sure it's http (and not https) as well at this stage.

Comment: When you run web api in VS, it will try to open the help page. As you stated below, if you get an error trying to start debugger, your service has a problem even running.

Comment: Yea, I get that error I posted below.. I guess something's wrong? Weird because it is the exact code running on another host.
"Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Windows.Services.Blah.MyAPI.WebApiApplication'; another partial declaration of this type exists"

Comment: the error is that two classes in the same namespace have the same name, You might need to debug that one. At least the website starts now :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help guys. I'll try to debug this.